# Unity: After downloading Google Ads Api "Could not convert classes into dex-format"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a little platformer that worked fine about 30 minutes ago. All I did no was importing the Google Ads Api as stated in those instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start

I followed them step by step.

Now, my game still plays fine in the editor - but I now want to deploy the APK to my phone. This crashes with

```
"CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
D:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -Xmx8000M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing bitter/jnibridge/JNIBridge.class
1 error; aborting
]
stdout["
```

This is followed by a long truncated list with much information. I am posting this upon request.

I then googled a bit around, and people said that this was caused by "duplicated files" usually coming from the Facebook API and the Google API both being imported to the same project.

However, as you may already think, the Google API is the first API I imported, so technically, there cannot be "two duplicate files", right?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have the same issue:

Download the newest JDK for Android (this comes together with Android Studio, so you need to install Android Studio, even if you dont want it).

After installing everything (including the newest JDK) remember the path your JDK is put to.

Now in Unity under settings, guide the interface to the JDK folder of your newest JDk you just downloaded. This fixes it :)